# R data.table summary function suffix or prefix

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I really appreciate the speed of the data.table package, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add a suffix to summary functions. The dplyr package does this wonderfully out of the box and I'm hoping that it's possible in data.table. Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(data.table)
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)
iris_dt = as.data.table(iris)

#Using dplyr

summary_stats <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE),sd(.,na.rm=TRUE)))

#Using data table
cols = sapply(iris_dt, is.numeric)
iris_dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = cols]

 names(summary_stats)
[1] "Species"           "Sepal.Length_mean" "Sepal.Width_mean"  "Petal.Length_mean" "Petal.Width_mean"  "Sepal.Length_sd"  
[7] "Sepal.Width_sd"    "Petal.Length_sd"   "Petal.Width_sd"   
 names(iris_dt)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

As you can see, using dplyr and multiple summary functions, a suffix it automatically added. This is very useful for me but it is pretty slow on larger data sets.

Can we do the same thing with data.table? Summarize all numeric columns by different summary functions and add the proper suffix to the output?

Comment: For a prefix, you can do `iris_dt[, c(m = lapply(.SD, mean)), .SDcols = cols]` just like in base R, `data.frame(c(x = iris))` for suffix, I guess you need to use setnames, maybe writing a helper function around the operation. (Use setnames not setNames, since the former modifies names by reference)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Frank's comment, if it's ok to have column names prefixed instead of suffixed, you could do:

```
my_funs <- c(mean = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
             sd = function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))

iris_dt[
  ,
  do.call(c, lapply(my_funs, function(fun) lapply(.SD, fun))),
  by = Species,
  .SDcols = cols # superfluous here
  ]

#       Species mean.Sepal.Length mean.Sepal.Width mean.Petal.Length mean.Petal.Width
# 1:     setosa             5.006            3.428             1.462            0.246
# 2: versicolor             5.936            2.770             4.260            1.326
# 3:  virginica             6.588            2.974             5.552            2.026
#    sd.Sepal.Length sd.Sepal.Width sd.Petal.Length sd.Petal.Width
# 1:       0.3524897      0.3790644       0.1736640      0.1053856
# 2:       0.5161711      0.3137983       0.4699110      0.1977527
# 3:       0.6358796      0.3224966       0.5518947      0.2746501
```

(*note*: in this particular case, since all columns but the grouping one are numeric, it seems superfluous to define `cols` and use `.SDcols`).